# Constructor of `NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle(String userDisplayName)` is deprecated

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, push-notification, android-notifications

I wanted to use `MessagingStyle` for my chat notification builder and I have only a username from the sender, I read in the documents and I found that I can use the `MessagingStyle(Person person)` constructor.

How can I instantiate MessagingStyle with Person?

```kotlin
val notificationBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder =
    NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID).apply {
        setShowWhen(false) 
        
        // Set the Notification style
        // setStyle(NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle(Person)) ??
        
        color = Color.WHITE
        setSmallIcon(R.drawable.chat_notif_small_icon)
        setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
        setContentIntent(contentPendingIntent)
        setOngoing(false)
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For details check this: https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/exploring-android-p-enhanced-notifications-a9adb8d78387

```
val sender = Person.Builder()
        .setName(R.string.user_name)
        .build()
```

Then use this as

```
NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle(sender)
        .addMessage("Check this out!", Date().time, sender)
        .setBuilder(notificationBuilder)
```